# Reference for Skinner-Urban on the Iwasawa main conjecture for $\mathrm{GL}_2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Does anyone know the existence of an expository paper or a report discussing the work of Skinner-Urban
"The Iwasawa main conjecture for $\mathrm{GL}_2$"?

I am interested in partucular in the case of elliptic curve (as in the end of section 3 of Skinner-Urban's work).

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wan's introduction (in Beenakker's answer) is freely available http://www.match.uni-heidelberg.de/publications.php  thanks to an agreement of Heidelberg math department with Springer.

Answer (score 7):

well, there is the [Ph.D. thesis](http://dataspace.princeton.edu/jspui/bitstream/88435/dsp01c534fn974/1/WAN_princeton_0181D_10237.pdf) of Skinner's student Xin Wan that generalizes the work of Skinner and Urban. He also wrote an "Introduction to Skinner-Urban's Work on the Iwasawa Main Conjecture for GL$_2$" in volume 7 of [Contributions in Mathematical and Computational Sciences](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-3-642-55244-1).

Answer (score 2):

Skinner gave a series of four lectures in IAS introducing the proof. IAS kindly provided the recordings on Youtube.

Lecture 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qdsct0VCXnE

Lecture 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFHeQMBk33k

Lecture 3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKBWyUaqxtw

Lecture 4: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMGLG4wFQfw

Unfortunately, the blackboard is sometimes not clear enough to read. One can refer to Wan's note to facilitate which is linked in one of the answer above.